# TTS BlackBerry API

Tags: blackberry, text-to-speech

Is there any API to use TTS (Text-To-Speech) in BlackBerry? This could be on any version of the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is what RIM has to say about Text to speech API

> The Text-To-Speech API in the BlackBerry® Java® Development Environment permits a developer to create a BlackBerry device
>   application that converts information into audio output. The Text-To-Speech API uses the JSR 113 specification (also known as
>   the Java® Speech API 2.0 specification) to support a speech synthesizer.
>   The developer can use the Text-To-Speech API and the Accessibility API to create a screen reader application. The Accessibility
>   API retrieves information from device applications and sends the information to the Text-To-Speech API. The Text-To-Speech
>   API can use the information that the Accessibility API provides to create audio output. For example, the Oratio™ for BlackBerry®
>   smartphones application uses the Accessibility API and the Text-To-Speech API to convert information into audio output for
>   users who are blind or visually impaired.
>
> Currently, RIM limits the use of the Text-To-Speech API.
>
> For more information about the JSR 113 specification, visit http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=113.

There are other apis which you can try

http://www.ispeech.org/text.to.speech.tts.saas.api

Answer (score 0):

Yes we have

Go to below link:

[Speech-Enable Your BlackBerry](http://www.ispeech.org/developers/blackberry)

And follow these steps.

1. First click on **signing up for a developer's account.** and get the key it is **FREE**.
   From this you can get **Two** keys. One for Device and another for simulator;

   - when you check on simulator you must have to give the simulator key;
   - when you signIn on application replace the simulator key with the Device key;
2. Click on **Sample Application** on that link.
3. click on **iSpeech BlackBerry Demo** to download the sample demo. Extract that zip file you can get the one **Lib** file. (if you want to do your own Add it to your application).

**NOTE:** If you not get the key then, the sample demo which is provided by that link does not work.